# Scala "primitive" optimisation

Tags: optimization, scala, types, primitive

In several places I have seen a declaration similar to:

"The Scala compiler uses Java arrays, primitive types, and native arithmetic where possible in the compiled code" 
(Programming in Scala book).
But in practise I am not seeing this, for example in the following code, the scala type is using more memory than the java type (which I calculated by using the totalMemory and freeMemory methods):

```
long[] la = new Array[java.lang.Long](1024 * 1024);
for(i <- 0 until la.length)
  la(i) = new java.lang.Long(0);

val La = new Array[Long](1024 * 1024);
for(i <- 0 until La.length)
  La(i) = 0l;
```

mem_used (java long):>> 28.811M

mem_used (scala long):>> 36.811M

I realise the scala Any type has additional overhead, but where is the optimisation happening?

Comment: Your methodology for measuring memory usage must be wrong. The results you're getting are nonsensical.

Comment: Besides the other mentioned issues, it's quite possible, that the Scala program is pulling in additional classes from the Scala libraries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why bother with such a convoluted way of trying to find out what gets compiled to what? Just run javap on a class and you'll see *exactly* what it is.

```
C:\>type La.scala
class La {
    val La = new Array[Long](1024 * 1024);
}

C:\>javap La
Compiled from "La.scala"
public class La extends java.lang.Object implements scala.ScalaObject{
    public long[] La();
    public La();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As the documentation of Runtime.freeMemory says, the value returned depends on when the last gc was done. So the error is likely in your way of measuring.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned I am running gc between each. I am aware that it isn't guaranteed that any cleanup is completed but you would hope so in this trivial case.

Comment: Since you're only allocating about 8MB, the garbage collector might not deem it necessary to clean up yet. You should post the measuring code.

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to measure memory usage in Java.  Anything you do that touches the memory subsystem will cause results to fluctuate wildly--and even if you do nothing, you can't be sure that the JVM isn't creating objects in order to run itself.  In particular, you should use `while` loops not `for` loops in order to fill the arrays (to avoid any creation of objects in the `for`).  Then again, the memory allocation that creates the array may trigger a garbage collection.  Your best bet is to run the jvm with `-verbose:gc` to make sure no garbage collections happen between your measurements, e.g.

```
println("Starting")
// Measure free memory
// Create some stuff
// Measure free memory
println("Ending")
```

and if you see the GC come in between Starting and Ending, ignore that run.